# How to convert cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am using an API to verify some data, and can get their cURL API to work from the command line like this:

```
curl --get --include 'https://domainnameher.com/?domain=whatever@virtual-email.com' \
-H 'X-Mashape-Key: f123456879' \
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

That returns some JSON - All good. When I try and convert it to PHP and run as a form processor script I don't get anything returned from the service.

HTML

```
<form id="testF" action="processor.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
    <input type="submit" class="redFlat" value="DOWNLOAD">
</form>
```

jQuery for AJAX

```
$(function(){
    $('#testF').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var dataString = $(form).serialize(); 
            $.ajax({
                type:$('#testF').attr('method'),
                url: form.action,
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

And main issue - the PHP processor. I'm taking the POST value from the form and appending it to URL...

```
<?php
    $email  = filter_var($_POST["Email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $fields = array('domain' => $email);
    $url = "https://mailcheck.p.mashape.com/?" . http_build_query($fields, '', "&");
    $endpoint = urldecode($url);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $headers = [
        'X-Mashape-Key: f123456879',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $server_output;
?>
```

I don't know why I'm not getting the same response from the script as I do when I run the command from terminal. Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: First thing, have you confirmed that the PHP script does not return the expected value, by posting to it directly in a browser? If so, you can get rid of the JS and HTML from your question.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `$endpoint = urldecode($url);` You will end up with invalid URLs if your email contains problematic characters like `+`.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed the PHP script returns nothing by taking out the js and directly posting to it.

Comment: Is this your problem? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: Before I used urldecode, it escaped the '@' symbol and it apparently the API needs it

Comment: No, the server would decode `%40` into `@` on their side.

Comment: damnit. yes, that was it. If you want points, put it in an answer and I will accept. Thank you, couldn't see the forrest from the trees.

Comment: so get rid of the URL decode?

Comment: Sorry, prematurely hit post on the answer, but I think that will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of nits to pick in your code aside from the obvious typo of `CURLOPT_POST`. You use `filter_var` but carry on if the filter fails; you should check for a false value. You should not be using `urldecode` on the URL, the whole idea of `http_build_query` is that it does the URL encoding for you. This one's a personal preference but I find `curl_setopt_array` much easier to work with. And, you should be checking if your result is valid JSON and use proper headers when sending the response back to jQuery.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$email  = filter_var($_POST["Email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (!$email) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    $res = ["result"=>false, "message"=>"Invalid email"];
    echo json_encode($res);
    exit;
}
$fields = ['domain' => $email];
$url = "https://mailcheck.p.mashape.com/?" . http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'X-Mashape-Key: f123456879',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ]
]);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

if (json_decode($server_output)) {
    echo $server_output;
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    $res = ["result"=>false, "message"=>"Invalid response from server: $server_output"];
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge. One question, why do you set header("Content-Type: application/json"); in the first line and then also in the CURLOpt_HTTPHeader - I'm assuming they are separate?

Comment: `header("Content-Type: application/json");` is telling your jQuery code what kind of data you're sending back. Generally it's smart enough to tell, but it never hurts to be explicit. Setting `Accept: application/json` in your request headers is telling the API what kind of data you'll accept.